# How can I set an alarm for the first Monday of each month?

Tags: calendar, alarm

I can set an alarm for every Monday, but how can I set one for only the 1st Monday each month?

I can have calendar events set in Google that are for first Monday, is there a way for an alarm to be set on a calendar event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention whether you are willing to buy an app to do this. I recently got an app called [Alarm Plus Millenium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.milleniumapps.freealarmclock) that I see can do this (and lots more).  I mainly got it for its task manager abilities, but I also needed a newer alarm clock app to replace my old unsupported Gentle Alarm, and this app was the best I could find for what I wanted.

Also, FWIW, I've had some email exchanges with the developer, and he was very responsive, quick to reply, and although in Paris, was very proficient in English (my only language).

Just saw your question about setting an alarm for Calendar events.  Yes, Google Calendar allows you to set all sorts of alarms for the events.  You can set more than one if you want.